# writing javascript code using javascript inside javascript file

Tags: javascript

It might be a silly question but let me ask. I want to assign a object or code snippet to a variable as string and use it or act it later as code.

```
code_string = "rules:{hotel_name:{required: true, lettersonly: true}}";

var validator = $('#create_hotels').validate({
    print code_string;
    //  How will I call code_string here to act as below ?
});

// want it working like this

var validator = $('#create_hotels').validate({
    rules:{hotel_name:{required: true, lettersonly: true}},
});
```

Comment: Why not use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse? you aren't exactly passing code, you are passing information.

Comment: Why not just store as object? `const rules={hotel_name:{required: true, lettersonly: true}} ..... $('#create_hotels').validate(rules)`

Comment: I updated my question little bit, please show me with working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a very small change, you can just parse your string to a javascript object.

The change is to include `{` and `}` in the string, but also format the string as valid json - which includes wrapping keys in `"`.

```
var code_string = '{"rules":{"hotel_name":{"required": true, "lettersonly": true}}}';
```

Now you can use `JSON.parse`:

```
var validator = $('#create_hotels').validate(JSON.parse(code_string));
```

Comment: I am having submitHandler and error element as well how it work with them

Comment: @mohsin you've changed the question since this answer was posted. You might be better to revert it (so as not to invalidate this and other answers) and ask another question. But in short, you're going to have problems with a string version of the submit handler. Not impossible, but can present a security concern

Comment: I revert my question but please if you can show me the example of submitHandler it will be great

Comment: @mohsin you can pass a string to the constructor of `Function` and execute it. https://jsfiddle.net/kwr5xe23/ This is a REALLY bad idea. Its is eval in disguise. See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/11/01/eval-is-evil-part-one/ and https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/

Comment: actually I have many forms and I am thinking of multiple forms validation solution

Answer (score 0):

```
code_string = '{"rules":{"hotel_name":{"required": true, "lettersonly": true}}}';

var validator = $('#create_hotels').validate({
    print JSON.parse(code_string);
});
```

follow the syntax of json while creating the string... then convert it as json where you need it

Answer (score -1):

Simplified, but should be easy for you to extend.

How about something like this?

```
const isValid = {
    name: str => str.length > 3,
    age: int => {
        const MIN_AGE = 18;
        const MAX_AGE = 65;
        if(isNaN(int)){
            return false;
        }
        return age >= MIN_AGE && age <= MAX_AGE;
    }
}

const john = { name: 'John', age: 21 };
const sarah = { name: '', age: 99 };

isValid['name'](john.name); // true
isValid['age'](john.age); // true

isValid['name'](sarah.name); // false
isValid['age'](sarah.age); // false
```

Comment: This answer confuses me - what's it got to do with the question?!